# Печать QTableView с сохранением форматирования

Tags: c++, qt

Есть `QTableView`, соединенная с `QSqlTableModel`, у это таблицы также есть делегаты и прокси модель. Возможно ли вывести данную таблицу на печать с сохранением всего этого форматирования?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например:

```
QString saveFileName = "table.pdf";

QPrinter printer;
printer.setOutputFileName( saveFileName );
tableView.render( &printer );
```

Comment: Странно, но он выгружает в pdf обрезанное изображение. Видимо, подгоняет под A4, обрезая

Comment: Плюс рисуются скролбары. Возможно ли экспортировать полностью всю таблицу, а не только то, что видно на экране?

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg, тогда предлагаю это [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079676/5909792). Там из QTableView формируется html, которое помещается в QTextDocument и оно уже печатает себя. Должно напечатать все страницы и без скроллбаров :)

Comment: Спасибо! Решил при помощи этого топика https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769680/printing-qtableview-using-render-method